# Changing header.html file in Zend Framework hides the text

Tags: php, html, css, zend-framework

I'm trying to replace the header.html and footer.html file written in Zend Framework. While the old header was located at `application/cache/header.html` and `footer.html` in the same location. I replaced those files with my new header.html and footer.html.

The css and js files and the rest of the code were included in the following manner in the file  `/application/modules/default/layout/global.phtml`:

```
echo $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($host . $this->basePath() .'/css/mycssfile.css')
                      ->prependFile($host . $this->basePath() . '/js/myjs.js');
```

The header and footer were loaded through the following code:

```
$headerPath = APPLICATION_PATH . '/cache/header.html';
$headerHtml = file_get_contents($headerPath);

$footerPath = APPLICATION_PATH . '/cache/footer.html';
$footerHtml = file_get_contents($footerPath);
```

Later in that page, the header and footer were appended in the following way:

```
<header id="header_rwd">
<?php echo $headerHtml; ?>
</header>
<footer id="footer_rwd">
<?php echo $footerHtml; ?>
```

After all this, when I open the home page the header and footer appear without any text over them.

Also I've some jQuery written in the header.html file. But none in footer.html file. Is it because of the jQuery or just some error thrown by css?

I searched many forums but was not able to arrive at any results.

I'm a beginner at Zend Framework and all I wanted to do is to change the header and footer file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a recommended way to render views in layout or any other view. You should use:

```php
<?php print $this->render('path/to/file'); ?>
```

Also, show your header and footer file content.